# why i am getting this error when i wrap MaterialApp with GetMaterialApp?

Tags: flutter-getx

/E:/Software/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_navigation/src/root/get_cupertino_app.dart:252:17:

Error: No named parameter with the name 'useInheritedMediaQuery'.useInheritedMediaQuery: useInheritedMediaQuery,
/E:/Software/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/app.dart:189:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don'
t match.
const CupertinoApp.router({
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/E:/Software/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_navigation/src/root/get_cupertino_app.dart:292:17:
Error: No named parameter with the name 'useInheritedMediaQuery'.
useInheritedMediaQuery: useInheritedMediaQuery,
/E:/Software/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/app.dart:145:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don'
t match.
const CupertinoApp({
^^^^^^^^^^^^
/E:/Software/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart:275:17: E
rror: No named parameter with the name 'useInheritedMediaQuery'.
useInheritedMediaQuery: useInheritedMediaQuery,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/E:/Software/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:217:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't
match.
const MaterialApp.router({
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/E:/Software/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.1/lib/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart:322:17: E
rror: No named parameter with the name 'useInheritedMediaQuery'.
useInheritedMediaQuery: useInheritedMediaQuery,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/E:/Software/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:166:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't
match.
const MaterialApp({
^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I could better understand your problem if you provided some code. But based on the title of your question,  my guess is that you should not wrap `MaterialApp` with `GetMaterialApp`. You should use `GetMaterialApp` **instead** of `MaterialApp`.